# Verificar e listar os arquivos de um diretório com PHP

Tags: php

Peguei recentemente um sistema para manutenção desenvolvido em PHP. O colega anterior não armazenou as imagens do upload no banco de dados ou o diretório. Para listar as imagens, o raciocínio é mais ou menos dessa forma:

As imagens está armazenada no diretório:

```
imagens/noticias/noticia_11.jpg
imagens/noticias/noticia_11_1.jpg
imagens/noticias/noticia_12.jpg
```

Onde é 11 e 12, consegui identificar que é o ID das notícias no banco de dados e 11_1 é mais uma foto do ID 11. Como tem muitas notícias, teria que refazer todo o sistema, mas não é essa a proposta do cliente então preciso trazer essas imagens para o site. Como eu faria para listar as imagens referentes ao ID? Algumas notícias não tem foto, então estou fazendo dessa forma:

O upload permite até 10 imagens:

```
public function listarFotos($idNoticia)
{
   ....
   for($foto = 1; $foto <= 10; $foto++)   
   {
     $foto = 'imagens/noticias/noticia/'.$idNoticia.'_'.$foto.'.jpg';
     if(file_exists($foto))
     {
       $visualizar .= '<img src="'.$foto.'">';
     }
  }
 return $visualizar;
}
```

Só que não está funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php) para listar os arquivos a partir de uma expressão regular:

```
$id = 11;
$imagens = glob("imagens\/noticias\/noticia_{$id}(_\d+)?\.jpg");

foreach ($imagens as $imagem) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez Anderson.